# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser for JavaScript Code Within the Page

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, domparser

I'm using PHP Simple DOM Parser, the HTML part is working as expected, but some of the content of the web page is shown with JavaScript. The JavaScript is within the HTML page not a separate file and the information I need is clear, in plain text.
This is how the JavaScript code starts, the information needed is in the end (location):

```
<script id="state">
    window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = {
        "detail": {
            "listingTopNavigation": {},
            "isTracked": false,
            "id": 30279925,
            "isImported": false,
            "isErotic": false,
            "isMessengerEnabled": false,
            "categories": [{
                "name": "Musique - Instruments",
                "id": 23,
                "isErotic": false
            }, {
                "name": "Guitares & Accessoires",
                "id": 697,
                "isErotic": false
            }, {
                "name": "Electrique",
                "id": 2354,
                "isErotic": false
            }],
            "imageData": {
                "baseUrl": "https:\u002F\u002Fcan01.anibis.ch\u002FElectrique-Line-6-DL-4-Delay-Modeler",
                "images": ["\u002F?[size]\u002Fanibis\u002F925\u002F279\u002F030\u002FLSmd7oN9LU6lAP5EbJQXXg_1.jpg", "\u002F?[size]\u002Fanibis\u002F925\u002F279\u002F030\u002Fhn2lNMOudUmuZofpM7wrsg_1.jpg", "\u002F?[size]\u002Fanibis\u002F925\u002F279\u002F030\u002FJKBbte21vEaD7ZJqcMi_Qg_1.jpg"]
            },
            "title": "Line 6 DL 4 Delay Modeler",
            "description": "\u003Cp\u003EVerkaufe mein Delay DL 6 in absolut neuwertigem Zustand wegen Nichtgebrauch. Das Delay habe ich im Dezember 2018 neu bei Musix gekauft und verfügt über eine tolle Auswahl an Delay Effekten, welche auf Fender Gibson Marshall oder Vox in Extraklasse daherkommen. Das Gerät ist optisch und technisch absolut neuwertig, kommt in Originalverpackung und mit dem passenden Netzadapter von Line 6. \u003C\u002Fp\u003E\n",
            "price": 190,
            "offerType": "Offer",
            "formattedPrice": "CHF 190.–",
            "formattedModified": "19.08.2019",
            "details": [{
                "name": "Remise",
                "value": "Retrait et envoi "
            }, {
                "name": "Type d’annonce",
                "value": "Offre"
            }],
            "location": {
                "country": "Suisse",
                "state": "Soleure",
                "zipCity": "4625 Oberbuchsiten (SO)"
            },
```

How can I get these values in PHP variables to use after.

```
$country = $html->find(...);
$state = $html->find(...);
$zip_city = $html->find(...);
```

Thanks.

Comment: personally, I'd recommend just using AJAX to pass the vars. JS and PHP should never mix.

Comment: Wrap your plain text into an additional set of { … }, then you can use json_decode to transform it into a PHP data structure that gives you easy access to the properties.

Comment: @misorude good idea, but the code I posted is just a part of the whole javascript, could you help me select only this part and wrap it alone? thanks!

Comment: If this is part of a larger JSON structure, it should probably still be parsed as that. You could go fishing around in the content using regular expressions instead, but that is not really that recommendable. Can you show a proper example of the actual content you need to extract this from?

Comment: @misorude Ok this is how the whole JS code starts, take a look at the edited question.

Comment: You’re gonna need some string functions or regular expressions then anyway. If you don’t want the necessary operations or patterns to get too complex, then maybe just cut off the leading `window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ` from that value (assuming the whole rest of that script element without that was valid JSON then, if there’s more after that that needs cutting of, you might need some additional steps, or something more complex after all.)

Comment: @misorude Thanks a lot! The code is now working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($html) {

    if ($html->find('script[id=state]', 0)) {

        $script = $html->find('script[id=state]', 0);
        $script = ltrim($script, '<script id="state">window.__INITIAL_STATE__=');
        $script = rtrim($script, '</script>');

        $obj = json_decode($script, true);

        if (isset($obj['detail']['contact']['phone'])) {

            $tel = $obj['detail']['contact']['phone'];
            $tel = ltrim($tel, '+41 ');


            if (isset($obj['detail']['location']['street']))
                $address = trim($obj['detail']['location']['street']);

            if (isset($obj['detail']['location']['zipCity']))
                $npa_ville = trim($obj['detail']['location']['zipCity']);
                $npa_ville = explode(' ', $npa_ville, 2);
                $npa = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $npa_ville[0]);
                $ville = $npa_ville[1];
```